gif в AVD android studio
У меня есть анимация логотипа, которая сохранена в gif.
Как мне ее использовать в android а конкретно в:
<item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" tools:targetApi="31">тут</item>

да, туда можно просто вставить gif, но при запуске она отображается некорректно
Подскажите как можно ее конвертировать в другой формат или сделать что бы эта gif была на весь экран (сейчас это маленький квадрат по центру а вокруг задний фон, заданный windowSplashScreenBackground)

так есть же оф. документация где сказано что нужен Vector Drawable
